# XSLT function to filter alphabets and phone number from phone number

Tags: xml, xslt, transform, transformation

I have to transform xml date into csv by using XSLT.
There is a field for phone number which may contains alphabets, space, country code(+1 for USA) as well as special characters too. I have to remove space, special characters, country code and alphabets and retain only 10 digits numerica value. I created below function which remove these except alphabets. To remove both set of alphabets (2*26), I have to use replace function 52 times if I followed this approach.

```
<xsl:function name="wd:gePhone">
        <xsl:param name="phone_number" />
        <xsl:if test="$phone_number !=' '" >
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace($phone_number,'-',''),'/',''),' ',''),'\)',''),'\(',''),'\+1',''))"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:function>
```

- Have you another apporach or function which filter alphabets
  too from such phone numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of several replace calls, each for one single character, you should use a character class:

```
replace(replace($num, 'a', ''), 'b', '')
```

can be rewritten as:

```
replace($num, '[ab]', '')
```

This can be used together with an alternative for the two-characters-long string `+1`:

```
replace($num, '[ab]|\+1', '')
```

And all characters from A to Z can be matched using a range `a-z` in the character class.  So reusing the same character as in your example, with the space normalization, it would be:

```
normalize-space(
   replace($num,'[-/,()a-zA-Z]|\+1',''))
```

Note that the character `-`, because it has a special meaning in a character class between 2 characters, can be used for itself if it is the first character after `[`.

Comment: Is it possible to shorten the size of this phone number by only 10 digit?

Comment: You can use `substring()` for length-based string manipulation.  But you'd need to tell us more precisely what you'd like to achieve (input, expected output, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to replace single characters, you can also use the translate() function

```
translate($num, "-/ ()", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:variable name="vnumsOnly"
            select="translate(Phone_Field, translate(Phone_Field, '0123456789', ''), '')"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($vnumsOnly, (substring($vnumsOnly, 1, 1) = '1') + 1)"/>
```